# Why does using using awk work fine, but if i assign a variable to said awk command it breaks anything that has a space in it?

Tags: bash, csv, variables, awk, space

I'm making a script that reads a CSV where I have placed the locations of various icons I want to put on a dock. If I run

```
awk -F "," '{print $1} test.csv
```

I will get:

```
/Applications/Launchpad  
/Applications/Safari   
/Applications/Pages  
/Applications/Numbers  
/Applications/Keynote  
/Applications/Photos   
/Applications/iMovie  
/Applications/GarageBand  
/Applications/Microsoft\ Word  
/Applications/Microsoft\ Excel  
/Applications/Microsoft\ Powerpoint
```

But if i assign that same command to variable this and run

```
 for i in $this; do
     echo $i;
```

the last three lines print like this:

```
/Applications/Microsoft\  
Word  
/Applications/Microsoft\  
Excel  
/Applications/Microsoft\  
Powerpoint
```

I understand that it's obviously breaking at the space and will need to fix it, but I don't understand why it works in one but not the other. **strong text**

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: The `awk` command in your question has a mismatched single quote. Please copy-and-paste the actual command you're using into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a Bash for loop splits on all whitespace, you can override it by setting `IFS=$'\n'` before loop

Test Results:

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat testfile 
/Applications/Launchpad  
/Applications/Safari   
/Applications/Pages  
/Applications/Numbers  
/Applications/Keynote  
/Applications/Photos   
/Applications/iMovie  
/Applications/GarageBand  
/Applications/Microsoft\ Word  
/Applications/Microsoft\ Excel  
/Applications/Microsoft\ Powerpoint
```

say you store your results using awk something like below

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ testvar=$(awk '1' testfile)
```

Default behaviour

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ for i in $testvar; do echo "$i"; done  
/Applications/Launchpad
/Applications/Safari
/Applications/Pages
/Applications/Numbers
/Applications/Keynote
/Applications/Photos
/Applications/iMovie
/Applications/GarageBand
/Applications/Microsoft\
Word
/Applications/Microsoft\
Excel
/Applications/Microsoft\
Powerpoint
```

this is with IFS

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ IFS=$'\n';for i in $testvar; do echo "$i"; done; 
/Applications/Launchpad  
/Applications/Safari   
/Applications/Pages  
/Applications/Numbers  
/Applications/Keynote  
/Applications/Photos   
/Applications/iMovie  
/Applications/GarageBand  
/Applications/Microsoft\ Word  
/Applications/Microsoft\ Excel  
/Applications/Microsoft\ Powerpoint
```

Comment: You're unsetting IFS? that seems worse than leaving it only set to newline

Comment: @WillBarnwell yeah thanks removed, you are right, could have used something like `IFS=$OldIFS`, or even `IFS=$' \t\n'`

Comment: sorry for the delay, but this worked for me; thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
for i in $this; do
     echo $i;
```

`$this` is expanded and then split by any of the characters in the [Internal Field Separator (`$IFS`)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars#ifs) variable which by default is tab, newline and space. To get the behavior you want we only want the string split on newlines so we set IFS to newlines using:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Playing around with the IFS should be done carefully, its recommended to hold the original IFS values in another variable and restoring them after the use of your modified IFS.

Or restore it to the original with:

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

So all together:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $this; do
     echo $i;
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

Should output what you want.

To answer **why** this happens this way. `awk` output is not subject to globbing or splitting, the expanded contents of variables are.

Answer (score 0):

Either do

```
awk -F "," '{print $1} test.csv | while IFS= read -r line; do 
    do_stuff_with "$line"
done
```

Or skip awk altogether

```
while IFS=, read -r first restOfList; do 
    do_stuff_with "$first"
done < test.csv
```

Resources:

- [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

  - this page explains why `IFS=$'\n'` is a bad idea.
- [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)